# Eclipse search multiple strings in any order, case insensitive

Tags: regex, string, search, eclipse-cdt

I think the title is pretty self-explanatory. I have a big project in Eclipse Juno CDT and I want to search the whole workspace for matches to the strings 'max' 'hfr' & 'fps'. For a successful match they must all be on the same row, in any order, case or count. They can be part of words (variable names), so it is not exactly a word search.
Is this a job for regex, and what regex exactly? Or is there a hidden search feature in Eclipse that can let me do that easily?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well what you want to do. You simply need to use the eclipse search tool with regular expression (CTRL + H or Search>Search in eclipse menu). You'll see there's a lot of option and possibilities to configure your research, including using regular expression. You just need to construct the right regexp.

I hope this will help.

Comment: So regular Eclipse search is off the table. I expected that, but can you help me construct the expression? I was never really good with regex.

Comment: Just have a look on how to build a regexp. I think it wouldn't be such a complex one. You might need beginning of line (^), end of line ($) and nothing more, maybe (+) to say that you want at least one occurrence of something.